# Got error while trying to change a SSR nuxt3 to SPA with ssr:false

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, nuxt3

I recently tried to change the rendering of my nuxt app to SPA mode with ssr:false but as soon as I did that I get the following error

```
Error while mounting app: TypeError: `target` argument of Proxy must be an object, got undefined
[entry.js:58:13](http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/Users/gitamgadtaula/Desktop/work/freelance/glrtec/frontend/node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/entry.js)
```

Below is my nuxt.config.ts

```
 // https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
 ssr: false,
 app: {
   head: {
     title: "GLRTECH",
     meta: [
       {
         name: "description",
         content: "Your portfolio management in a smart fashion",
       },
     ],
     link: [
       { rel: "icon", href: "/favicon.ico" },
       {
         rel: "stylesheet",
         href: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons",
       },
     ],
   },
 },
 imports: {
   // auto importing files from store and composables directory
   dirs: ["stores", "composables"],
 },
 css: ["@/assets/css/style.scss"],
 modules: [
   "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss",
   "@formkit/nuxt",
   "@pinia/nuxt",
   "@vueuse/nuxt",
 ],
 pinia: {
   autoImports: ["defineStore"],
 },
 tailwindcss: {
   viewer: false,
 },
 vite: {
   // plugins: [
   //   // ...
   // ],
 },
});
```

Can anyone please help? I am using the latest version of Nuxt 3.4.0

​

Answer (score 0):

Figured out its an issue in the latest version of nuxt 3.4.0, downgraded to 3.3.3 and and it just works fine.